# Полученное от функций значение, выводит ошибку при обработке JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

При обработке функции, переданное в обработчик JQuery значение, вызывает ошибку.
Если поменять `result` на строку, которую он передает, то событие отрабатывается как задумано. 
При использовании преобразователей в строку ошибка пропадает, но ничего не происходит.

```js
let u1Day = [11, 15, 16];
$('#u1').mouseover(function(){
 $(getNum(u1Day.length)).css('color', 'goldenrod');
});
function getNum(num) {
  let localCount = 0;
  let pieceRght = (" +')");
  let result = ("$('.calCell:contains('+ ");
 for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  localCount = i;
   function localLft(numLft) {
    if (numLft > 0) {
     lft = (".calCell:contains('+ ");
    } else {
     lft = "";
    }
    return lft;
   }
   function localRght (numRght) {
    if (numRght == (num - 1)) {
     rght = (pieceRght + ("');"));
    } else {
     rght = (pieceRght + (",")); 
    }
    return rght;
   }
  result += (localLft(i) + u1Day[i] + localRght(i));
 }
return result;
//return $('.calCell:contains('+ 11 +'),.calCell:contains('+ 15 +'),.calCell:contains('+ 16 +')'); //Try this to look at correct value
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
   <td><button class="calCell">11</button></td>
   <td><button class="calCell">15</button></td>
   <td><button class="calCell">16</button></td>
</tr> 
<p id="u1">Hello!</p>
```

Очень нужен совет, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы немного перемудрили. Как Вы думаете, что будет, если передать в функцию `jQuery` такую строку?

```
"$('.calCell:contains('+ 11 +'),.calCell:contains('+ 15 +'),.calCell:contains('+ 16 +')');"
```

```js
let u1Day = [11, 15, 16];
$('#u1').mouseover(function() {
  //console.log(getNum(u1Day.length));
  var $a = eval(getNum(u1Day.length));
  $a.css('color', 'goldenrod');
});

function getNum(num) {
  let localCount = 0;
  let pieceRght = (" +')");
  let result = ("$('.calCell:contains('+ ");
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    localCount = i;

    function localLft(numLft) {
      if (numLft > 0) {
        lft = (".calCell:contains('+ ");
      } else {
        lft = "";
      }
      return lft;
    }

    function localRght(numRght) {
      if (numRght == (num - 1)) {
        rght = (pieceRght + ("');"));
      } else {
        rght = (pieceRght + (","));
      }
      return rght;
    }
    result += (localLft(i) + u1Day[i] + localRght(i));
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><button class="calCell">11</button></td>
  <td><button class="calCell">15</button></td>
  <td><button class="calCell">16</button></td>
</tr>
<p id="u1">Hello!</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ очень помог. Существуют еще какие-то варианты, где достаточно откорректировать результат функции?

Comment: @Stanislav Не понял последний вопрос. Вы компонуете строку, содержащую кодовое выражение. Это выражение в какой-то момент должно стать кодом и быть выполнено.